# « Une phrase à incise(s) » ou « une phrase avec incise(s) »

Tags: prépositions

Doit-on choisir pour *« Une phrase … »* la première ou la seconde construction ?

Le modèle vivant :

> — « C’est *un homme* ***à*** femme(s) »
>
> — « C’est *un homme* ***avec*** femme(s) » [et enfant(s)]

s’autorise les deux, selon le contexte ou l’intention de l’auteur. L’Académie accorde-t-elle la même liberté aux utilisateurs de sa langue pour construire leurs phrases ?

Comment: Aucune source, mais pour moi *phrase à incise* c'est le concept alors que *phrase avec incise* ça ne fait que décrire la phrase dont il est question.

Answer (score 1):

L'Académie, je ne sais pas, mais aucune des deux formes ne me choque.

*Phrase à incise* semble plus élégant que *phrase avec incise*, mais c'est cette dernière tournure qui est la plus couramment employée et c'est même la seule que trouve Google Books.

Une raison est peut-être que *phrase **avec** incise* s'oppose plus clairement à *phrase **sans** incise*.

Comment: Oulipo : "Phrase à incise" sise dans la bise courtise la banquise : « — m'attise ou me défrise ? — Bigreeu ! Un Tigreeu … et ’Greeu' !! » plus rien ne rime, plus rien ne vient à dessein … monde incertain ! si "avec" me cloue le bec aussi sec, après tout, Bout-ddh"à" s'en fou. Freux-d et Corneilles sont dans ce choix … à la noix.